# Amazon WS S3: I'm getting this error message: "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint."

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

how can I address the bucket using the correct endpoint? I'm using Django to create my app.

I've seen a solution for this in a different language and I couldn't understand a thing, is there a solution for Python?

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*******************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '*************+'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

The images url starts like this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nostalg.ia/media/(...)

When it should start with the image destination like I see in all tutorials.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way we can help...

Comment: what about now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regional endpoint  to make your requests. The general syntax of a Regional endpoint is as follows:

```
protocol://service-code.region-code.amazonaws.com
```

For example:

```
https://mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to do with this information, how can I make my endpoint use this syntax? I'm really new to Django and Amazon WS, sorry.

Comment: should be able to access any file in your bucket by visiting http://<BUCKETNAME>.s3-website-<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<FILENAME>.

Comment: But how can I make this format the default for my images so that they show up on my app? Thanks